# asp.net mvc image path and virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I know this has to be a duplicate, but I've been wading through the hordes of information on this and I can't get it work.

I'm trying to get a site working on a client's server and they have the site installed in a virtual directory.  I don't have this setup, locally, so I'm flying blind here.

I'm trying to build a path to an image. (it's for Facebook OpenGraph Meta data).

I need the path to the image to be a fully-qualified, absolute url.  I've tried so many things, but nothing seems to work.  The code below outputs a relative url, but this will not work.

```
<% var urlHelper = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/static/images/image.jpg");%>
<meta property="og:image" content="<%=urlHelper%>" />
```

outputs:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/static/images/image.jpg" />
```

I've also tried:

```
<% var serverHost = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url; %>
<meta property="og:image" 
          content="<%=serverHost + "/static/images/image.jpg"%>" />
```

But that's producing:

```
<meta property="og:image" 
   content="http://localhost:51863/ViewFile.aspx/static/images/image.jpg" />
```

I'm looking for http://example.com/virtualdirectory/static/images/image.jpg

Any help will be much appreciated.  I really don't want to have to hard-code the url.

Thanks,
Scott

### EDIT

I neglected to mention that my very first attempt was Url.Content("~/....jpg) but that outputs a relative url, not an abosolute one.

Comment: Why not host it in a virtual dir in your dev environment then you wouldn't have to fly blind any more

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write a small extension method:

```
public static class UrlExtensions
{
    public static string AbsoluteContent(this UrlHelper url, string contentPath)
    {
        var requestUrl = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;
        return string.Format(
            "{0}{1}",
            requestUrl.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority),
            url.Content(contentPath)
        );
    }
}
```

and then:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<%= Url.AbsoluteContent("~/static/images/image.jpg") %>" />
```

which will output for example:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://localhost:7864/static/images/image.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 11):

This code

```
public static class Helpers
{
  public static Uri FullyQualifiedUri( this HtmlHelper html , string relativeOrAbsolutePath )
  {
    Uri        baseUri  = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url ;
    string     path     = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl( relativeOrAbsolutePath, new HttpContextWrapper( HttpContext.Current ) ) ;
    Uri        instance = null ;
    bool       ok       = Uri.TryCreate( baseUri , path , out instance ) ;
    return instance ; // instance will be null if the uri could not be created
  }
}
```

should work for pretty much any URI you can throw at it.

One thing to note, though: page-relative URIs (such as `foo/bar/image.png`) might not resolve the way you think they might, especially if the URI references a directory, so you get the default page (i.e., `http://localhost/foo/bar` could be an actual resource, in which case the URI is complete, or it could be incomplete, in which case Asp.Net MVC's routing fills in the blanks. All the request has is the original URI. If you want to fix that, you'll need to get the `RouteData` for the request and interrogate it for the details.

Here's how things resolve with a web app rooted at `http://localhost/MyApp` and invoking the Html helper method in different ways from the `About` view of the `Home` controller.

- `~`

  - resolves to `http://localhost/MyApp/`
- `/`

  - resolve to `http://localhost/
- `~/`

  - resolves to `http://localhost/MyApp/`
- `foo/bar/myImage.png`

  - resolves to `http://localhost/MyApp/Home/foo/bar/myImage.png`
- `/foo/bar/myImage.png`

  - resolves to `http://localhost/foo/bar/myImage.png`
- `~/foo/bar/myImage.png`

  - resolves to `http://localhost/MyApp/foo/bar/myImage.png`
- `http://somesite.com/foo/bar/myImage.png`

  - resolves to `http://somesite.come/foo/bar/myImage.png`
- `http://somesite.com:123/foo/bar/myImage.png`

  - resolves to `http://somesite.come:123/foo/bar/myImage.png`
- `ftp://somesite.com/foo/bar/myImage.png`

  - resolves to `ftp://somesite.come:123/foo/bar/myImage.png`
- `mailto://local-part@domain.com`

  - resolves to `mailto:local-part@domain.com`

Comment: +1 I found this answer really informative and solved my problem. I needed to find the home path (either //localhost/MyApp/ or //website/) no matter where it was running so that my javascript redirection would work.

Comment: Can you help telling me how can I test this? (using UrlHelper)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the routing to resolve your URLs.

Personally I like to follow the [best practices guide here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx) to:

> Create Extension methods of UrlHelper
>   to generate your url from Route

You'll likely want an extension method for these static images you have:

```
public static string StaticImage(this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
    {
        return helper.Content("~/static/images/{0}".FormatWith(fileName));
    }
```

then you can do:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<%: Url.StaticImage("image.jpg") %>" />
```

Comment: I'd suggest using MvcContrib instead to have compile time check of the "urls"

Comment: I started down this best practices as you referenced, but my setup didn't recognize .FormatWith(). Could it be that I'm using MVC2 and that's for MVC1?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Content` method on the `UrlHelper`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx