# Get absolute url of a file in an MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following on an Asp.Net MVC 5 site:

```
@Url.Content("~/shareimage.jpg")
```

This gives me a relative url. But I need the absolute url.

How can I get the absolute url of a file?

thank You,
Miguel

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net mvc image path and virtual directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509120/asp-net-mvc-image-path-and-virtual-directory)

Answer (score 2):

Url.Action or url.RouteUrl where a protocol is specified gives you the absolute url.

```
<%= Url.Action("About", "Home", null, "http") %><br />
<%= Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { Action = "About" }, "http") %><br />
```

http://captaincodeman.com/2010/02/03/absolute-urls-using-mvc-without-extension-methods/

Comment: That, I think, is for ASP.NET Forms not for MVC

Comment: Please, read my question ... I am using Url.Content but that gives me the relative path.

Comment: Yes, I know Action and RouteUrl have a protocol option but that is for action not for files ... And Url.Content does not have it ... That is the problem

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of this question: [asp.net mvc image path and virtual directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509120/asp-net-mvc-image-path-and-virtual-directory).

I use this helper myself:

```
public static class Helpers
{
  public static Uri FullyQualifiedUri( this HtmlHelper html , string relativeOrAbsolutePath )
  {
    Uri        baseUri  = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url ;
    string     path     = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl( relativeOrAbsolutePath, new HttpContextWrapper( HttpContext.Current ) ) ;
    Uri        instance = null ;
    bool       ok       = Uri.TryCreate( baseUri , path , out instance ) ;
    return instance ; // instance will be null if the uri could not be created
  }
}
```

which should give you a fully-qualifed absolute URI for pretty much any URI your throw at it.